# Aptana Ruble for Jquery does not work properly

Tags: jquery, aptana, bundle

I have installed the Aptana Ruble for jQuery exactly as explained on http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/JavaScript+Library+Support (both ways, for Studio 3.0.1+ and 3.0.5+).

Everything seems to work correctly on Ruble installation. All the files where downloaded from git into my ~/Documents/Aptana Rubles/ directory. No error happened.

I have checked both "jQuery 1.6.2" and "jQuery 1.4.2" on "Project Build Path" on the Project Settings. I also have restarted Eclipse several times...

**It insists on not showing code completion options for Jquery.**

I type `$('p').` and ctrl + space and "No Default proposals" appear.
I also type `jQuery('p')` and and ctrl + space and "No Default proposals" appear.

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 2 
with Aptana Plugin Version: 3.0.6

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not that this should matter, but what OS are you using?

Comment: By the use of ~/ I assume Filipiz is using a mac. At present I am having the exact same problem - can't for the life of me figure out how to get code complete to work :(

Comment: Well, a bit of progress. I installed the standalone Aptana 3 (on a mac) and the jQuery code complete works exactly as expected. There isn't even a requirement to add any rubles or have a copy of the jquery file in the project - it just works. Now I'm going to try and see what the difference between this and the eclipse set up I have is.

Comment: So I have got jQuery to work in Eclipse, although now not sure how. Made sure that I was in a 'web' project, that the js file association is to 'Javascript Source Editor' type (I think this was the default, the editor view will be Aptana 3 white text on black background). I hope that it wasn't anything to do with installing Aptana separately. I get the impression that as an IDE Eclipse and Aptana are changing quite a lot at present - smart move to tie rubles into TextMate so that the development community is larger...

Answer (score 1):

The "LanguageType" + "Source Editor" editor types are provided by the Aptana studio, whereas the "LanguageType" + "Editor" is from Eclipse (i.e. not compatible with the Aptana bundles, although you will be able to see the commands, you cannot complete them).This is true for PHP, too. Unfortunately, there are some ways that the PDT is superior to the Aptana Studio plugin-provided "PHP Source Editor", but overall I'm starting to feel that the benefits of the PHP bundles (e.g. for Drupal development, for Wordpress dev) and for jQuery, not to mention the better support for renumbering when turning on Word Wrap (another plugin), make the Aptana Studio better, overall, so I've assigned the Aptana "source" editors for all language types and started to remove other redundant plugins to reduce the load and compatibility issues.

In short, editors with "source editor" in the name support using the Rubles/bundles, whereas the editors which you had in Eclipse before installing Aptana Studio do not. Hope that helps others... I was stumped by this for some time, too.

Comment: Many hours, 5 highly voted SO-Qestions, 3 reinstallations and dozens of Blog-posts to get work the content assistent for jQuery in Studio 3 - finally your zero voted Answer helps. Thx a lot.